# Implement Matlab's eps(x) function in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, epsilon

I'm trying to implement Matlab's `eps(x)` function in C++

For example, in Matlab:

```
>> eps(587.3888)
ans = 1.1369e-13
>> eps(single(587.3888))
ans = 6.1035e-05
```

However, when I try to do this in C++ I am not able to get the correct single precision answer.

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

#define DEBUG(x) do { std::cerr << x << std::endl; } while (0)
#define DEBUG2(x) do { std::cerr << #x << ": " << x << std::endl; } while (0)

int main() {

    float epsf = std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
    DEBUG2(epsf);
    double epsd = std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
    DEBUG2(epsd);

    float espxf = nextafter(float(587.3888), epsf) - float(587.3888);
    double espxd = nextafter(double(587.3888), epsd) - double(587.3888);
    DEBUG2(espxf);
    DEBUG2(espxd);

}
```

Running the program I get the following output:

```
$ ./a.out 
epsf: 1.19209e-07
epsd: 2.22045e-16
espxf: -1.13687e-13
espxd: -1.13687e-13
```

It seems as though for some reason even though the eps values for single and double precision are correct, the output using `nextafter` function only outputs the double precision value.  My value for `epsxf` should be 6.1035e-05 as it is in Matlab.

Any thoughts?

Comment: MATLAB's `eps` always gives positive results. The above code would give negative results if `x` is greater than `epsf`. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68546c8c401c0610)'s the fixed code: `double eps(float x) { float xp = std::abs(x); double x1 = std::nextafter(xp, xp + 1.0f); return x1 - xp; }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include `<cmath>` and call `std::nextafter`, and your code will work, provided you have a C++11 compiler.

Including `<math.h>` and calling `::nextafter` invokes the C version of the function. The C implementation of `nextafter` obviously supports no overloads, so C provides a `nextafterf` for single-precision result, as well as `nextafterl` for quad-precision. (Simply calling double-precision `nextafter` with `float` fails because the argument gets converted to `double`.) If you don't have a C++11 compiler, you can fix your code by invoking `::nextafterf`.

Answer (score 3):

Use libraries. Matlab's [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) function in other languages is called ULP, for unit in last place. According to Wikipedia article on [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place#Language_support), the following function from the [boost C++ library](http://www.boost.org) can be used to calculate the floating point distance between two doubles `a` and `b`:

```
boost::math::float_distance(a, b)
```

The documentation for `float_distance` is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/next_float/float_distance.html).

Comment: yes, thank you I was aware of the boost implementation, however for our class we are not able to use the boost libs.

Comment: I really wonder how in the world this answer rates a down vote. Not only did I explain the concept of ULP, but I suggested a robust alternative solution that works for both single and double precision. The OP had not indicated the his wish not to use boost.

Comment: There's a +1 for you to balance out the -1. Thanks for the background info on ULP. Helpful to understand as I try to implement this in Go.